# Emphasize first line of paragraph in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, paragraphs, emphasis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the style of the first *typeset* line of a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/changing-the-style-of-the-first-typeset-line-of-a-paragraph)

Trying to find out how to emphasize the line of text automatically. The issue here is that I have no idea where the line would break.

Ideally it would be start paragraph with `\sl` and then insert `\rm` upon first line break.

For now I manually make something like `\def\\{\break\rm}` and inserting `\\\` after a certain word in the beginning of paragraph, manually trying to choose minimal first line looseness.

Would be nice if `parshape` supported that, so we could make

```
\parshape=N [indent_1] [width_1] [modifier_1] [indent_2] etc...
```

Or if there would be something like "`everyline`", similar to `everypar`.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Don't use `\sl` or `\rm` in modern LaTeX documents! use `\sffamily`, `\rmfamily` or better `\textsf{...}` and `\textrm{...}` instead. See [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/2975](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it) for an explanation.

Comment: Rather than highlighting the first line, have you considered highlighting the first *idea*, as expounded under `\newthought` on ~page 21 of [the tufte-latex example book](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf), or by using the `\(sub)paragraph{}`  commands?

Comment: Martin - well, thanks. Mostly used tex before, but tired of its low-level nature.

Comment: Brent - that's exactly what I did before with lettrine package - dropped capital followed by two or three slanted words. But after that I started wondering how to do something like to "The Wizard Knight"  http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5094/5488837854_d3e6a68d88_z.jpg

Comment: Yes - completely the same issue. Should I remove this question?

Comment: No, we can just close it as duplicate.