# How can I automatically change the font qualities of the first few words of a chapter?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, automation

First off, TeX knows about words (since it does different spacing for inter-letter, inter-word, and inter-sentence.
There must be a way to tap into this.

As for the Q, what I mean is emulating the common practice of many maths books ([for example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486240614)) of changing the font family, shape, size, or *some transformation* to the first few words of each chapter (or section, or ...).
How can this be automated with TeX?

---

I have a way that works (below), but it has its own funkiness and I'm interested in seeing others' solutions.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86296/why-does-a-color-meant-for-the-first-typeset-line-only-with-package-magaz-af

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, that's cool! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to define some macro:

```
\def\autocaps #1 #2 #3 {\textsc{#1 #2 #3} }
```

and then hook it onto any command I choose.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% I'm not really sure what #1 is capturing here, but it's whitespace.
\def\autocaps #1 #2 #3 #4 {\textsc{#2 #3 #4} }
\let\oldsection=\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \oldsection*{#2}%
  }{%
    \oldsection{#2}%
  }%
  \autocaps
}

\begin{document}
\section{The beginning}
The real challenge comes with\dots
\section*{The end}
Now that the challenge is out of the way, \dots

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `#1` is the (nothing) before the  white space after the `}` of the section title. Note you are disabling the optional argument to section.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oops, you're right.  I can fix the optional argument thing, but why would it pick up (nothing) before the `}` and then continue to pick up arguments *after* it?

Comment: `#1` is everything up to the first space, the first space is the one immediately after the `}` (the end of line is converted to a space by the time the macro is expanded) and there is nothing before that so `#1` is an ampty argument, like `{}`