# Processing a particular line of text in a document

Tags: line-breaking, parsing

My question points actually to a particular problem, as opposed to the more general type of problem suggested in the title -- which would nevertheless be interesting to me to see answered: I'd like to have the first line of text after a section (or chapter) heading set in small caps.

If this were about automating such a processing task for a given number of words starting after the sectional heading it would be an easy thing to do, but how could this be done for exactly an entire line of running text? Maybe with just a little better knowledge of TeX on my side I would not be making this question, but I don't know...

An answer on TeX, LateX2e or even LaTeX3 to the particular setting ("small caps") would be welcome and enough for my checking it (as long as it works, of course). And if there is some suggestion for the more general problem, that'd be simply wonderful: Let's say (just for the sake of concreteness and without pretending that what follows is a rigid spec) that "a given line" in the more general setting means "the line in which a particular string is to be found", and the "particular string" might be marked up in terms of some command. The processing, of a nature similar to the "small caps transformation" I'm concerned with in the particular setting, is to be applied to the entire line in which the string will eventually appear in the typeset document (i.e., once the processing has been performed).

PS: My tags for this question may not be the most fortunate, but they are the closest I could see among those provided.

Comment: related, possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86296/why-does-a-color-meant-for-the-first-typeset-line-only-with-package-magaz-af/86307#86307

Comment: @David Carlisle: Right. I didn't know about the ``magaz`` package. I have to look at it more closely, but it seems it solves the "small caps" problem in my OP. I wonder if it could be extended in the sense of the general issue I address.

Comment: extending it might be hard: it's massively difficult to do that much in TeX (Donald Arseneau knows more than most about manipulating TeX parshapes:-)

Comment: So... does it make any sense providing an answer in these terms? From what you say, it seems most unlikely that somebody is going to provide an alternative in the affirmative.

Comment: Not sure I have anything to have as an answer, you could make a self-answer with small caps, or close as duplicate, or perhaps Heiko will step in with a general solution:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: I was thinking of expanding your comment about the difficulty of extending it. That'd would make for an answer, at least if nobody else came up with an "affirmative" one. I couln't provide an answer to the "small caps" setting because, even though the OP that you linked to was addressing a different question, the answer is in the ``magaz`` package itself.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I may not have been clear on my comment due to faulty English grammar. I meant that I was thinking of you (as opposed to me) expanding on your comment to turn it into an answer.

Comment: :-) well I don't like to predict the future, it wouldn't be easy but I don't want to say it can't be done:-) OH OK as we don't like unanswered q's...

Comment: Some say that answers in the sense of impossibility are just a display of lack of imagination, but this is not a negative answer anyway ;-) With regard to our disliking unanswered questions... LOL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic functionality of adjusting the typesetting of the first line is handled by the `magaz` package. Note a small adjustment to that to help with color support is in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86296/why-does-a-color-meant-for-the-first-typeset-line-only-with-package-magaz-af/86307#86307). Extending the package to support lines other than the first is likely to be hard (the package already does more than one would expect possible given the nature of TeX's paragraph breaker).

Comment: Answer checked for its constructiveness in the waiting for a "more affirmative" contribution... if possible.