# Special layout for first lines

Tags: page

Some publishers (at least some French ones) use the following layout at the beginning of each chapter of a book.

The first line of the first paragraph appears in large font (say `\Large`) with no indentation. The second line is in smaller but still large font (say `\large`) the third line uses the normal font size but blackface. The special layout ends with line 4 (I assume here that the paragraph has at least four lines).

I have tried to devise how this could be achieved but I have only found (nice) things about lettrines.

I do not include a MWE since I have no clue where to begin and my MWE would be useless.

I am including an example of the layout taken from a book publised in 2012.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[expansion]{alltext}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLayout=true,og= «,fg= »}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\begin{document}
\chapter{Le sang des terrassiers}

{\bfseries{\Large Métro, canaux, voies ferrées, tun-}{\large nels, les
    chantiers se multipliaient dans} la France de la Belle Époque, en
  milieu urbain comme en pleine nature, faisant partout surgir} les
terrassier ou «taupiers». Souvent fils de ruraux sans terre, ceux-ci
entraient dans le métier vers l’âge de seize ans. La Bretagne et
l’Auvergne fournissaient les plus gros contingents mais ils étaient
nombreux aussi à venir d’Italie. Les apprentis les plus jeunes, qu’on
appelait «les mousses», n’avaient pas plus de quatorze ans.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4143/579) deals with the first line only.  the documention for the `magaz` package that it mentions says that "maybe" special formatting might be addressed for the first n lines (but the package is dated 2011).  however, the author is still active, and it might be worth asking him.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks indeed for the pointer. I'll have a look.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `magaz` works well for the first line. I have no clue on what to do for the second or third lines. Does the "maybe" in the documentation means "not for now".

Comment: I have a pretty large collection of French books but I’ve never seen this.  Do you have an image you could share, or can you point to a particular publisher’s catalog?

Comment: @Thérèse I'll dig in my library. But I have not invented the layout.

Comment: I don’t suspect you of inventing it, but I’m having trouble picturing it. And I’m a little confused, because you have this question tagged “lettrine” but what you describe seems not to use lettrines.

Comment: @Denis -- that's why i suggested asking the author; the address in the package documentation was still valid earlier this year.

Comment: I have added an image with the layout I had in mind. It took me some time to find an example. Also, yes, I might contact Danald Arseneau, the author of `magaz`.

Comment: @Thérèse Sorry this is not what I intended to mean.

Comment: I’ve added an example for you, meant to work with pdftex. I assume your question is how to do this automatically instead of by trial-and-error. In luatex, I think this could be done with a callback, but my lua skills aren’t yet sufficient.