# How to continuously change the font size line by line?

Tags: fontsize

Suppose I have a huge amount of text. I'd like to typeset it so that it starts with a massive font (e.g., 100pt) and with each new line becomes slightly smaller (e.g., by 99%) so that by the end of the document it's unreadably small (e.g., 2pt).

For a given set of text I could insert font size changes at just the right place after line breaks, but this will take a lot of effort and will need to be repeated if I change the text even slightly.

Is there a way to do this programmatically with pure Latex?

Comment: do you have to change the font at linebreaks (which is hard) or for example at every word (which is a lot easier)

Comment: There’s a somewhat similar, as yet unanswered question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/423200

Comment: every word is interesting, too, but really I'd like it to be line-by-line